# Preventing all changes to be staged when git stash pop has a conflict

Tags: git

I noted the following behavior with git. When I stash pop a previously stashed changeset, it will be restored without any addition to the staged area. If I however get a conflict at the stash pop, all the changes will be staged for commit. Is it a bug, or a feature that can be disabled? If the latter, I am interested in how to do so.

git version is 1.7.9.5

Comment: I'm thinking that git believes that you are in the middle of a merge, so that you are in a temporary state, while a clean pop would have cleaned up the temporary state. Doesn't answer your question but may give you a hint of where to look..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it can, and I agree it's a bit annoying. AFAIK it's a side-effect of the merge driver. However, you can easily unstage everything using `git reset HEAD .`.